# Popup Dialog Not Re-drawing after initial launch

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-mvc

I have a dropdown listbox on my main page with a button on the same page that launches a pop-up dialog box, also having a dropdown list box. I need the selected index of the 1st listbox control to be synched with the pop-up dialog dropdown listbox.

I have added code to my Controller that sets the index in the ViewData object to be retrieved by the popup and it works on the initial launch of the App. My problem is any subsequent launches of the pop-up dialog won't hit its corresponding code to set the index using the ViewData. The code that needs to be executed is:

```
<%= Html.Telerik().DropDownList()
                      .Name("DataStoreTypeId")
                      .BindTo(new SelectList(Model.DataStoreTypes, "DataTypeId", "Name",Model.DataTypeSelectedId))
                      .HtmlAttributes(new { style="width:205px })
                      .SelectedIndex((int)ViewData["SelectedIndex"])
                %>
```

Coming from an ASP.NET background, I am accustomed to having postbacks as mechanisms to handle these types of actions, but MVC has trimmed the postback events which is great for performance but what are my options to force code execution now?

Should I be using other alternatives?

Comment: Does it work with Html.DropDownList ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First time it works because its value is set on server side. once its rendered in the browser there is no server side left. you have to manually change the selected value of your telerik dropdown list on button click event next to your first drop down list (is first DD also telerik dropdown or html one). For client events of telerik dropdown have a look at [Telerik Demos for asp.net mvc](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/combobox/clientsideevents)

Comment: Thanks for the tip and yes the 1st DD is also a telerik control. The link you provided is a good resource but I believe there simply isn't a way to acheive the behavior I'm looking for based on the lack of responses to my question, your explanation and after having viewed the link. I guess my only option is to find a hack to get it to work. None of the available events cause a postback to the server to retrieve the newly selected index of the first dropdown. I am beginning to see why Telerik controls for MVC are free. :-)

Comment: @Mark its too soon to be disappointed. Telerik controls for mvc are great, that i can tell you based on my experience. Postback is not the only way to set the values of controls. with mvc you need to learn some javascript for client side manipulation.